# What can I do with an old modem

Tags: modem

After watching this video here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9dpXHnJXaE it made me wonder if there is anything I can actually do with some old 56k modems I've got from old computers.

Obviously I don't have anything that old but still. So is there anything at all that I can do with them, e.g. connecting to something else or would that require me to go back to dial-up.

Answer (score 4):

One option is set up your computer to be able to send and receive faxes.

Comment: One obsolete technology after the other :)

Comment: faxes continue to be used today...

Comment: @kokbira: which doesn't in any way mean they aren't still obsolete. Companies that require them are neglecting to engaged in the multitude of better, quicker, more secure, and less problematic and tempermental technologies available to them. And I say this as someone working at a company that makes extensive use of faxes.

Answer (score 4):

Use them to build a post-modern sculpture representing the ephemerality of human communications.

Answer (score -2):

I you're a hacker, you're a hacker. If you want to be a hacker, you start by trying. What to do with old modems is up to you. Maybe there's a need? You'll be the one best able to know. Maybe it's just there to do? You'll still be the one to know.

There are few systems (and shrinking daily) that still require a modem. Most of them are proprietary and come with their own modems. It's highly unlikely that you'll find yourself in a situation where you'll think "I wish I'd kept that old modem". It just isn't like to happen.